# How to test for an item in a radio set

Tags: radio-button, openedge

In OpenEdge Progress, I want to add an item to a radio set, but first I want to test to make sure that it is not already there so it won't be duplicated.  Is there a better way to do this other than :

dummy-log = radioset:delete(value) no-error.
dummy-log = radioset:add-last(label,value).

Using :delete causes issues if the current record has this as a screen value.

We use OpenEdge Release 10.2B05.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RADIO-BUTTONS` attribute gives you the label/value pair list for the radio set. You can then look for the value in it before adding a new one.

```
IF LOOKUP(value, radioset:RADIO-BUTTONS) = 0 THEN
    dummy-log = radioset:add-last(label,value).
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  I'll try that.